# Hide tables or forms in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to hide a element of `HTML` when I click in other element. 
I have a menu with a submenu that has two options. One option shows a table and the other a form. When I click on the first option, the table appears. If after I click on the second option, the previous table and the form appear.

The menu is:

[image: menu]

In action I get a table and in another action I get a form.

The code in `HTML` is:

```
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="origin()">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="formOrigin()">Another action</a>
       </div>
       <div>
          <table class="table"></table>
       </div>
       <div>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="city">City</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="city">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
               <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="add">
               <label class="form-check-label" for="add">Check</label>
            </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>

       </div>
```

The code in `Javascript` is:

```
    function origin() {

        var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/origin";
        petition.onreadystatechange = ResponseOrigin;
        petition.open("GET", url, true);
        petition.send();
        }

    function ResponseOrigin(){
        var response;
        text="<tr><th>Identifier</th><th>Name</th><th>Numero</th><th>City</th></tr>";
                if (petition.readyState == 4)
                    if (petition.status == 200) {
                        responser = petition.responseText;
                        var responseC = response.split("<");
                        var responseV = responseC[0];
                        var data = JSON.parse(responseV);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                text += "<tr id =" + data[i].id + "><td>" + data[i].id + "</td><td id='name'>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + 
                                data[i].city + "</td>                                 

                        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = text;

                        document.formOrigin.style.display="none";
                    }
                    else alert("Problem with URL");
            }

     function formOrigin() {


         var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/origin";
            petition.onreadystatechange = responseAddOrigin;
            petition.open("POST", url, true);
            petition.send(JSON.stringify({name: document.formOrigin.name.value,
                city: document.formOrigin.city.value}));

       }
      function responseAddOrigen(){

            var response;
            if (petition.readyState == 4)
                if (petition.status == 200) {
                    response = petition.responseText;
                    alert ("data recorded correctly");
                }
                else
                    alert("Problem with URL");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using bootstrap, you can try this:

```
$('yourTriggerElement').click(function(){
    $('yourTargetElement').addClass('d-none');
});
```

This add bootstrap class 'd-none' to your target element, which is the same as display none. You can add some conditionals if you want to show the element again with the same trigger. Change 'yourTriggerElement' and 'yourTargetElement' with your real id's or classes.

Comment: and what does 'this' do?

Comment: add bootstrap class d-none to the target element, which is display none.